# AUSampler Factory Presets MacError -1073748960

Tags: objective-c, ios, macos, cocoa, core-audio

When I attempt to receive property information about the factory presets for an AUSampler, I'm receiving an error number I cannot decode.

```
UInt32 datasize = 0;
Boolean writable;
OSStatus result = AudioUnitGetPropertyInfo(inComponentInstance, kAudioUnitProperty_FactoryPresets, inScope, (AudioUnitElement)0, &datasize, &writable);
```

The OSStatus code returned is -1073748960.  This doesn't return anything when I run:

```
macerror -1073748960
```

Any ideas what the error is?  I'm trying to investigate if there are factory presets available for the AUSampler.

Answer (score 0):

Your datasize variable should be initialized with the value of `sizeof(Boolean)`